# Search by one query in prodecure

Tags: sql, sql-server, search

In my website I have one field for search by name, zip, guid etc. Now it works only for name. I wrote a simple query

```
where (funeral_home_name like CONCAT('%', @searchFilter ,'%')) OR (funeral_home_zip5 like CONCAT('%', @searchFilter, '%'));
```

and it works fine, but I need to insert this code into exists procedure with 'case' statements

```
where funeral_home_name like case when @searchFilter != '' then CONCAT('%',@searchFilter,'%') else '%' end ...
```

So how I can do it?

Comment: why not construct dynamic where clause and add it while executing?

Comment: It's generally better to use `AND`/`OR` constructions instead of `case` _expressions_ in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: There are hundreds of similar questions out there, but the best answer going is probably [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html) by Erland Sommarskog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write each `OR` condition separately like following. You can't do it with a single condition like you get using `IN`

```
where (funeral_home_name like CONCAT('%',@searchFilter,'%') 
        or funeral_home_zip5  like  CONCAT('%',@searchFilter,'%') 
        or [guid] like CONCAT('%',@searchFilter,'%')) 
        or @searchFilter =''
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would use boolean logic:

```
WHERE funeral_home_name LIKE '%' + @searchFilter + '%'
   OR searchFilter = ''
```

This keeps your query SARGable, however, what you have here is a Catch-all query. Therefore you'll want to either add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to your query, or use dynamic SQL and create the appropriate `WHERE` clause for the value of `@searchFilter`.

Answer (score 1):

try this. This uses logic conditions instead of CASE statements.

Note: assumed guid column is `funeral_home_guid`

```
WHERE (@searchFilter='' or (funeral_home_name Like '%'+searchFilter+'%' 
                            or funeral_home_zip5 Like '%'+searchFilter+'%' 
                            or funeral_home_guid like '%'+searchFilter+'%'))
```